# Creating a column, where the value of each row is a key of a specified dict, based on whether existing column contains that dict value as a substring?

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have the following dictionary
`dict = {'a': ['tool', 'device'], 'b': ['food', 'beverage']}`,

and I have a dataframe with a column with the first 2 row values as
`'tools'`,
`'foods'`
and I want to create a new column where the 1st value is `a`, and the second is `b`.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Can you give an example of your desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First dont use varable name `dict`, because builtins (python code word). Then are swapped values of dict - values with keys for new dict, get values from column by [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) by keys of dict and [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by dictionary for new column:

```
d = {'a': ['tool', 'device'], 'b': ['food', 'beverage']}
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['tools','foods']})

d1 = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in d.items() for k in oldv}
print (d1)
{'tool': 'a', 'device': 'a', 'food': 'b', 'beverage': 'b'}

df['new'] = df['col'].str.findall('|'.join(d1.keys())).str[0].map(d1)
print (df)
     col new
0  tools   a
1  foods   b
```

Or:

```
df['new'] = df['col'].str.extract('({})'.format('|'.join(d1.keys())), expand=False).map(d1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This did exactly what I wanted.